# How do I render a field in the gsp page from another domain?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

Here is my scenario:

```
Class Domain1 {
  static hasMany=[ tests : Domain2 ]
  static constraints = { tests(nullable: true) }
}
```

And

```
Class Domain2 {
  Double t1, String t2
  static constraints={
    t1(nullable:true
    t2(nullable:false,blank:false)
  }
}
```

I need to display t1 from domain2 in domain1 with the ability to edit.

Comment: Do you want to render a list of text fields in the web page, one for the `t1` in every element in `d1.tests`?

Comment: Yes. That's the idea. I am bit lost. I tried to use ```g:textField``` like ```<g:textField domain = "Domain1' name="tests" value="${tests.t1}" />```.

Comment: It would be more like `<g:textField name="t1" val="${domain1VarName.t1}"/>` where `domain1VarName` is the name of a model variable that points to an instance of `Domain1`.

Comment: I tried that. The problem is it displays the entire Domain value with id, something like ```Domain1:10``` representing domain class and the corresponding id. I want to display the exact value for ```t1``` here and if there is no value I would like to be able to add a new one.

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  If the `value` attribute is `${domain1VarName.t1}` and `domain1VarName` points to an instance of `Domain1`, then the value of that instances `t1` will be rendered, not an entity id.  It might be the case that the value of `t1` happens to be the same as the `id`, but `t` is a `Double` in `Domain2` which could have any value.

Comment: No, the id and value for t1 aren't the same.  I have very similar to this ```<g:textField name="t1" val="${tests.t1}"/>```.

Comment: When you do `${tests.t1}` is `tests` an instance of `Domain2`?

Comment: I mistype above.  I meant that doesn't sound right. If the value attribute is `${domain2VarName.t1}` and `domain2VarName` points to an instance of `Domain2`, then the value of that instances' `t1` will be rendered, not an entity `id`. It might be the case that the value of `t1` happens to be the same as the `id`, but t is a `Double` in `Domain2` which could have any value.

Comment: No, it is domain one. Something like this ```<g:textField bean= "${domain1Instance}" name="t1" val="${tests.t1}"/>```. Is that the problem?

Comment: "No, it is domain one." - If `tests` is a `Domain1` then `tests.t1` should throw a MissingPropertyException.

Comment: I think I have confused you and myself here. I am not too sure now the difference between ```${domain2VarName.t1} ```  and ```${domain1VarName.t1}``` in the above context. what I have is ```<g:textField bean= "${domain1Instance}" name="t1" val="${tests.t1}"/>``` and it is not throwing any exception. It is just showing ```Domain2:id``` and not letting me update or add new value.

Comment: Is the hasMany relationship above problematic?

Comment: Apologies.  I thought you said that `tests` was a `Domain1`.  I am sorry I don't think i can help you with this.  Best of luck!

Comment: No need to apologize. I appreciate your inputs. All of them have helped in some way or another.  Feel free to add comments if you think of any better ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to display t1 from domain2 in domain1 with the ability to edit.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/samdomain.

[grails-app/domain/samdomain/Domain1.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/samdomain/blob/410dd1a8bb2e93c3beccf13365de8300fc9f5799/grails-app/domain/samdomain/Domain1.groovy):

```
package samdomain

class Domain1 {
    static hasMany = [tests: Domain2]
}
```

[grails-app/domain/samdomain/Domain2.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/samdomain/blob/410dd1a8bb2e93c3beccf13365de8300fc9f5799/grails-app/domain/samdomain/Domain2.groovy):

```
package samdomain

class Domain2 {
    Double t1
    String t2

    static constraints = {
        t1 nullable: true
    }
}
```

[grails-app/controllers/samdomain/DemoController.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/samdomain/blob/410dd1a8bb2e93c3beccf13365de8300fc9f5799/grails-app/controllers/samdomain/DemoController.groovy):

```
package samdomain

class DemoController {

    def index() {
        def d1 = new Domain1()
        d1.addToTests t1: 42, t2: 'Fourty Two'
        d1.addToTests t1: 2112, t2: 'Twenty One Twelve'

        [domainInstance: d1]
    }

    def update() {
        render "Updated values: ${params.t1Values}"
    }
}
```

[grails-app/views/demo/index.gsp](https://github.com/jeffbrown/samdomain/blob/410dd1a8bb2e93c3beccf13365de8300fc9f5799/grails-app/views/demo/index.gsp):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>Simple Demo</title>
</head>

<body>

<g:form action="update" method="POST">
    <table>
    <g:each var="d2" in="${domainInstance.tests}">
        <tr>
            <td>${d2.t2}</td>
            <td><g:textField name="t1Values" value="${d2.t1}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
    </table>
    <g:submitButton name="Update"/>
</g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is much helpful. In another approach, is it possible to create a new domain2 object as a field from the web page for domain1?

Comment: " is it possible to create a new domain2 object as a field from the web page for domain1?" - Definitely.  You can put whatever form fields you like in the gsp and then use them to create whatever domain object you like on the server.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example using domain1 and domain2 from the above scenario?